# Cross-Reference com vetor de ponteiros

Tags: c, lista

Estou criando uma cross reference de um vetor de ponteiros que chama uma lista encadeada simples. Objetivo é digitar uma frase e decompor suas palavras, colocando elas em cada posição do vetor de acordo com sua respectiva letra inicial.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<conio.h>


void Menu()
{
                     printf("\n\nBem vindo ao programa de texto\n");
                     printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    printf("\n1 - DIGITAR TEXTO                                                            |"); 
                    printf("\n2 - IMPRIMIR TODAS AS PALAVRAS                                               |");
                    printf("\n3 - LISTAR PALAVRAS DE UMA LETRA                                             |");
                    printf("\n4 - QUANTIDADE TOTAL DE PALAVRAS                                             |");
                    printf("\n5 - REMOVER  PALAVRA                                                         |");
                    printf("\n6 - REFERENCIA TOTAL                                                         |");
                    printf("\n7 - REFERENCIA DE UMA LETRA                                                  |");
                    printf("\n8 - PALAVRA COM MAIOR QUANTIDADE                                             |");
                    printf("\n0 - SAIR DO PROGRAMA                                                         |");
                    printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                     printf("\n");
}


struct Palavra
{
    char palavra[40];
    int quant;
    struct Palavra *next;

};

struct Palavra * referencia[26];

void InsereLetra(char palavra[])
{
    int pos;
    pos=palavra[0]-'A';
    printf("\n POS:%d",pos);
    if(referencia[pos]==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nestou aqui");

        struct Palavra * p = (struct Palavra *)malloc(sizeof(struct Palavra ));
        strcpy(p->palavra,palavra);
        p->next=NULL;
        p->quant=1;
        referencia[pos]=p;


    }else
    {
        struct Palavra * aux=referencia[pos];
        struct Palavra * ant=aux;
        struct Palavra * ant2=aux;
        while(ant!=NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(palavra,ant->palavra)==0)
            {
                //printf("\nestou aqui2 cont %d",ant->quant);
                (ant->quant)++;
                printf("\nestou aqui cont %d\n",ant->quant);
                return ;

            }
            ant=ant->next;
        }
        while(ant2->next!=NULL)
        {
            printf("\nestou aqui3");
            ant2=ant2->next;
        }
        printf("\nestou aqui54\n");
            struct Palavra * p = (struct Palavra *)malloc(sizeof(struct Palavra ));
        strcpy(p->palavra,palavra);
        p->next=NULL;
        p->quant=1;
        ant2->next=p;
    return ;    
    }

}


void convert(char aux[])
{

    int i;
for( i=0;aux[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        aux[i]= toupper(aux[i]);

        if(aux[i]=='Ã'||aux[i]=='Á'||aux[i]=='Ä'||aux[i]=='À'||aux[i]=='Â')
    {
        aux[i]='A';
    }
    if(aux[i]=='É'||aux[i]=='È'||aux[i]=='Ë'||aux[i]=='Ê')
    {
        aux[i]='E';
    }
    if(aux[i]=='Í'||aux[i]=='Ì'||aux[i]=='Î'||aux[i]=='Ï')
    {
        aux[i]='I';
    }
    if(aux[i]=='Õ'||aux[i]=='Ó'||aux[i]=='Ö'||aux[i]=='Ò'||aux[i]=='Ô')
    {
        aux[i]='O';
    }
    if(aux[i]=='Ú'||aux[i]=='Ù'||aux[i]=='Ü'||aux[i]=='Û')
    {
        aux[i]='U';
    }

    }
    aux[i]='\0';    
}
int main()
{
    char ck,c;  
    int i,cont=0;
    for(i=0;i<=25;i++)
    {
        referencia[i]=NULL;
    }

    do{
        Menu();
    char frase[500],frase2[500];
        scanf("%d",&i);
        switch(i)
        {
                            case 1:
                                        setbuf(stdin, NULL);
                                        printf("\nDigite a frase:");



                                        fgets(frase,500,stdin);
                                            convert(frase);
                                        printf("\n");
                                            char * pch;
                                         printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",frase);
                                         pch = strtok (frase," ,.-:?;");
                                         while (pch != NULL)
                                         {
                                            //palavra
                                          printf ("%s\n",pch);
                                          //head=
                                          InsereLetra(pch);
                                          //LETRA
                                         // printf("%c\n",pch[0]);
                                          pch = strtok (NULL," ,.-:?;");
                                          }
                                setbuf(stdin, NULL);
                             break;

                                case 2:
                                        printf("\nIMPRIMIR TODAS AS PALAVRAS");
                                    //   imprimirPalavras(head);
                                    for(i=0;i<=25;i++)
                                       {

                                        if(referencia[i]!=NULL)
                                           {
                                            struct Palavra * aux=referencia[i];
                                            while(aux!=NULL)
                                               {
                                                printf("\n%s",aux->palavra);

                                                aux=aux->next;
                                               }
                                           }
                                       }
                                 break;

                                case 3: 
                                     printf("\nLISTAR PALAVRAS DE UMA LETRA");
                                     printf("\nDigite uma letra");
                                     scanf("%c",&ck);
                                //   listLetra(head,ck);

                                break;  
                                        case 4:
                                        printf("\n QUANTIDADE TOTAL DE PALAVRAS");
                                        //quantPalavras(head);
                                        break;
                                 case 5:
                                    printf("\nREMOVER PALAVRA");

                                 break;
                                     case 6:
                                    printf("\nREFERENCIA TOTAL");
                                //  refPalavras(head);
                                //Imprimir
                                     break;
                                 case 7:
                                    printf("\nREFERENCIA POR LETRA");
                                //Imprimir
                                    printf("\nDigite uma letra:");
                                    scanf("%c",&c);
                                //  refLetra(head,c);
                                 break;
                                     case 8:
                                    printf("\nPALAVRA COM MAIOR QUANTIDADE");   
                                //  maiorQuant(head);

                                     break;

                                case 0:
                                    printf("\n\nSaindo do programa...\n");
                                 break;


        }
    }while(i!=0);
}
```

O problema que estou tendo é digitar 2 ou mais vezes a mesma palavra em uma frase, independente de quantas vezes for o programa está gravando na lista 2x a mesma palavra. Tentei colocar os printf para eu poder ver se achava o problema, ele está entrando quando é lista nulla, e está executando o printf 54 que não deveria, pois uma vez testado acima, se a palavra for igual ele só deveria incrementar o contador e retornar. Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você depura um programa, regra geral acha o erro com certa facilidade. 
No caso acontece que a frase que é lida com `fgets` deixa-lhe o `\n` na string, como seria esperado. Por esse motivo quando lê a frase:

```
carro casa carro
```

Na verdade o *split* vai lhe dar as seguintes 3 palavras:

```
carro
casa
carro\n
```

E por isso o ultimo `carro` é diferente do primeiro, embora visualmente não pareça. Consegue testar isto com facilidade quer imprimindo a `string` que recebeu, quer testando com uma palavra que não se repita no fim.

Para corrigir basta acrescentar a seguir a leitura do `fgets` a instrução para remover a quebra de linha que ficou:

```
fgets(frase,500,stdin);
int posicao_quebra = strcspn(frase, "\n"); // achar onde está a quebra de linha
frase[posicao_quebra] = '\0'; // fazer a string terminar na quebra
```

O [`strcspn`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/) acha-lhe a posição do que foi passado no segundo parâmetro, neste caso a quebra de linha e faz a string terminar nesse local colocando o `\0` nessa posição.

Comment: muito obrigado me ajudou muito!!!! Está funcionando 100%! A principio não conhecia essa função strcspn adicionei ela e está 100%